# Does CloudFormation expose the Reader Endpoint of a Redis ElastiCache Replication Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation

I need to expose the Reader Endpoint of my Redis ReplicationGroup so it can be used by dependent CloudFormation stacks.

I've previously used the primary endpoint, which is available as a CloudFormation return value, but I now need to use the Reader Endpoint, introduced in June 2019 [https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/amazon-elasticache-launches-reader-endpoint-for-redis/].

However the Reader Endpoint does not appear in the Return Values in the CloudFormation documentation [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html]

My stack outputs are defined as:

```
MyReplicationGroup.PrimaryEndPoint.Address
MyReplicationGroup.PrimaryEndPoint.Port
```

Is the Reader Endpoint available, but not yet documented?  Perhaps the following is all I need?

```
MyReplicationGroup.ReaderEndPoint.Address
MyReplicationGroup.ReaderEndPoint.Port
```

I'd rather not use the ReadEndPoint.Addresses and ReadEndPoint.Ports as these are lists of replicas, and I then need to programmatically choose which to connect to - the Reader Endpoint will do all that for me (that is the whole point of it).

Comment: There is a `primary` NodeGroupMembers in the Replication group, which is the entry point of the first node - and is read-write. But I think is safer to expose the cluster endpoints rather than a node endpoint, as that one could be more volatile and be replaced in case of failure.

Answer (score 4):

Reader Endpoint Address is not currently exposed.

> But there is a relationship between a *Primary Endpoint* and a *Reader
>   Endpoint* which you can utilize.

Suppose you have a primary endpoint **one.two.three.com**.
Then reader endpoint would be **one-ro.two.three.com**.

In this way, you can generate the address for a Reader Endpoint with the help of a corresponding Primary Endpoint.

> **Note**: I know this is not the permanent solution but for now as a
>   workaround we can deduce the Reader Endpoint with the help of the Primary
>   Endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I think while waiting for the reader endpoint to be exposed (as per a request on the CloudFormation roadmap), we'll resort to using this, albeit with the risk that this format could change without notice and break our automation.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to resort to raising an issue on the [Cloudformation coverage roadmap](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap) to make the Reader Endpoint attributes available for use in Cloudformation.

Comment: thanks for pointing out this resource - I've raised an issue requesting this as output.

Comment: Issue link: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/210

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html#aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup-return-values) still say it is not supported, but I've just given it a try and it worked:

```
!GetAtt MyReplicationGroup.ReaderEndPoint.Address
!GetAtt MyReplicationGroup.ReaderEndPoint.Port
```

Comment: Hero! This worked for me too. Thanks for noticing this undocumented behavior.

Comment: This discovery was also discussed and confirmed in the official Github issues: [AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup - add reader endpoint output #210](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/210#issuecomment-686681002)